# System.ArgumentException: 'Palabra clave no admitida: 'metadata'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

¿Cómo soluciono el error?

> System.ArgumentException: 'Palabra clave no admitida: 'metadata'.'

el cual me indica la linea  `conec = new SqlConnection(conexion);`

Este es el código completo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ProyectoDicar.Models
{
public class gestionUsuario
{
    private SqlConnection conec;

    private void Conectar()
    {
        string conexion = 
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SidcarEntities"].ToString();
        conec = new SqlConnection(conexion);
    }

    public int Borrar(int codigo)
    {
        Conectar();
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("delete from articulos where 
codigo=@codigo", conec);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@codigo", SqlDbType.Int);
        comando.Parameters["@codigo"].Value = codigo;
        conec.Open();
        int i = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conec.Close();
        return i;
    }    

}
}
```

Comment: Revisa que la cadena de conexión este escrito correctamente en el Web.Config.

Comment: Nos puedes compartir como se define la propiedad **SidcarEntities** en el `configurationManager`, el error debe estar ahí como lo indica @waimaku

Comment: Revisa este enlace, esta explicado: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642474/setting-up-connection-string-in-asp-net-to-sql-server. Saludos

Comment: ese `SidcarEntities` es generado por Entity Framework... No va a funcionar. Publica tu `web.config` para ayudarte :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para solucionar ese error solo basta con estás linea.

```
String cadena = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NameCadenaConexion"].ToString().Split('"')[1];
```

pero si quieres tener la información detallada y la cadena de conexión entonces debes hacer lo siguiente.

```
            String cadena_conexion = 
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NameCadenaConexion"].ToString();

            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new  
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cadena_conexion.Split('"')[1]);
            String servidor = builder.DataSource;
            string base_de_dato = builder.InitialCatalog;
            bool autentificacionWindows = builder.IntegratedSecurity;
            String usuario = builder.UserID;
            String contraseña = builder.Password;
            String cadenaValida = builder.ConnectionString;
```

**Nota**
para poder usar algunos métodos que se usaron anteriormente debe importar esta referencia en tu proyecto
**System.Configuration**